# How to Match Point Data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point

How do I match the same points (WGS84) in two different point layers? I want to get the points that lie exactly upon each other in the two datasets.

Answer (score 3):

**In QGIS 1.7** you can use the Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect

[image]

Then if you want the attribution matched you can do a spatial join (join attributes with spatial location in the Data Management Tools) standard tools with QGIS.

Comment: @ Mappertz: Tried your suggestion but the resulting shapefile has null attribute table (no matching values) and i'm sure there should be some matching points

Comment: @akinboj: If the result is empty, there are no exactly same points in your dataset. You could consider reducing coordinate precision.

Comment: @Underdark: You were right. There was no exact match hence the null value. What I did was to use buffer to select matching points within a distance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear, in any case, when you have layers in different CRS just enable "on the fly CRS transformation" in the project properties.

Please be sure that your layers are read with their correct CRS, looking in the layer "properties" dialog, "general" tab.